# Make a small computer using Intel chips

Tags: microprocessor

Is it possible to make a small computer from scratch using Intel processors? I am not talking about any advanced version like i7 or anything. Just 80236 or any old processor like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, of course, however it will take a lot of effort (and a bit of money.) Nowadays you would most likely use a microcontroller just because you need far less peripherals, and you could get it completed so much faster and cheaper.

This is a crazy article, [Man builds computer from scratch, **including the CPU**!](http://dvice.com/archives/2011/05/man-builds-comp.php) [Here](http://www.bigmessowires.com/bmow1/) is the original link, thanks to [Kaz](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/9414/kaz).

This is pretty much exactly what your asking about, [William's Homemade Computer.](http://dubel.org/computer/) It runs on an old Intel 486DX @ 20 MHz. I'm not sure if the software is complete, but it looks quite cool!

[image: Homemade computer]

> But consider If I want to make a operation at 500MHz speed, what
>   should I do?

**Update** *Yes you can, although it would require a lot more work since at high speeds there are many more things to worry about, like impedance, matching trace lengths, noise, etc. However like I said you can. There are many new devices made that use an Intel Atom processor and operate in the Ghz range.*

For something running that speed, you would need to have a printed circuit board made, and assuming you're using an Intel processor, you would need to have the whole chipset, memory, etc. on that PCB. I really don't recommend it. You could probably get an older mother board and play around with it, otherwise you basically have to create it all on your own and that is just a lot of time, money and effort.

However if you use a 32bit ARM instead of an Intel processor, it would be completely doable and not too expensive. Something like the [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) is a fast computer that runs at about that speed and only costs $35 USA. It would of course be more expensive to make your own, but not too much.

---

Take a look at [How to build an 8-bit computer from scratch.](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/128035-how-to-build-an-8-bit-computer-from-scratch) The picture looks like a wiring mess from hell!

[image: wiring mess from hell]

Take a look at some of these videos:

- [Homemade mini i86 DOS computer with propeller chip for io's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCj2deCFMnc)
- [How to Build a Computer ... from scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYLPCMdY5Mw)
- [Homemade 6809 computer plays blackjack!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Dd1y3rbPck)
- [Homemade computer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIheNgLI_GM)

---

> In old time how could people like Steve Jobs come up with new
>   computers, designed by themselves. He didn't have any chip design
>   company like Intel. Then how could he arrange the chips necessary for
>   his computers?

He used ICs and processors to make the first computer in his parents garage, [Apple I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_I). In fact the Apple I was a fully assembled circuit board containing about 60+ chips. However, to make a working computer, users still had to add a case, power supply transformers, power switch, ASCII keyboard, and a composite video display.

[image: Apple I]

You can buy/build a replica of that computer nowadays for ~$200 USA. Take a look at the [Replica 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replica_1).

[image: Replica 1]

Some pictures of Steve Job's first computer, from [here](http://www.cultofmac.com/202657/these-are-some-of-the-first-apple-computer-photos-ever/):

[image]

[image]

[image]

You may want to take a look at the [history of computers](http://library.thinkquest.org/11309/data/history.htm).

Comment: But consider If I want to make a operation at 500MHz speed, what should I do?

Comment: @sree I edited my answer to address your question. But short answer, it's not worth it!

Comment: In old time how could people like Steve Jobs come up with new computers, designed by themselves. He didn't have any chip design company like Intel. Then how could he arrange the chips necessary for his computers?

Comment: @sree actually he did have chips, not exactly like what you are thinking of, but basic logic ICs. I'll add some examples to my post.

Comment: "people like Steve Jobs come up with new computers" Easy. He got other people to do the actual design and construction :P

Comment: The real URL for "big mess o wires" is here: http://www.bigmessowires.com/bmow1/

Comment: @sree If you want 500 Mhz, then that is kind of at odds with using an 80286 chip, which maxed out at, what was it, 12? 16? Some clones went faster.

Comment: @Kaz thanks, I updated the post with the link. 12Mhz was the top of the line 80286, it started out at 4Mhz and went up by about 2Mhz every new release. And it was only a 16bit chip that could do ~1.5 MIPS @ 10Mhz. Crazy to think of the advances that have been made!

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie Also, in a real way, these 70's and 80's chips were a regression from the discrete component mainframe machines of the 1960's, which broke the 30 Mhz barrier. The overwhelming selling point was still the price, size and power consumption.

Comment: Why this post is closed? "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form". Which one of the above point is applicable here?

Comment: @sree probably vague and overly broad. It happens, it's not a big deal.

Comment: @Inquisitive: The question fails on a couple of fronts. (1) "Is it possible ...?" Yes. (2) If it was possible then why would it not be possible now? (3) Zero research. (4) The implied question is "How can I build a 286 computer?" and this is beyond the scope of an answer here.